# 2 dimensional vector of class objects initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

I am trying to create 2-dimensional vector inside another class and initialize it:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class T2{
public:
    int a;
    T2(int a){
        this->a=a;
    }
};

class Test{
public:
    vector<vector<T2>> vec;
    Test(){
        auto tmp = vector<T2>(10,T2(1));
        vec = vector<vector<T2>>(10, tmp);
    }
};
```

Clion says that "call to vector is ambiguous"

Comment: cannot reproduce on GCC 7.2.0. Compiles fine for me

Comment: Is that what CLion says, or an actual compiler output? The two are not one and the same. Also, since you didn't include headers, your example is not a [mcve], which makes it harder to answer.

Comment: do you have another homemade class called 'vector'?

Comment: @Fureeish -- What was posted does not compile.  Let the OP provide the proper headers.

Comment: @StoryTeller this is what clion says. It compiles and works. I thought that if clion underlines something that means that this is wrong.

Comment: @peterSweter: copy and paste the **exact** error, with more context of the errors. I'm sure the error is *not* that small.

Comment: @peterSweter - Something is indeed wrong... with CLion

Comment: I compiled and ran it with VS2015, on windows 2012 Server, and QT Creator, on OSX, with clang, and it ran without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code to clion and it's working fine.
The only warnings found:

1) single-argument constructors must be marked as explicit

2) unused variables/function

I'm running:
CLion 2017.3.1; 
Build #CL-173.4127.32, built on December 26, 2017;

btw:

```
// auto tmp = vector<T2>(10, T2(1));
// vec = vector<vector<T2>>(10, tmp);
vec = vector<vector<T2>>(10, vector<T2>(10, T2(1)));
// you don't have to use tmp vect here
```